# In React app, converting class components to functional components, how to re-work this setState instance?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In a React app, I have a class component that acts as a form, and each different element of the form calls the same reusable function to set state in order to save data to state until the form is finished, then a callback to pass the data around elsewhere, and when that form is finished, it writes the data in state to a MongoDB. In calling the function, I pass a parameter into it that determines which property of state is set.

I'm trying to convert this component to a functional component, but can't come up with as elegant of a way to handle this using useState.

The function:

```
    handleChange = (e, t, l) => {
        if (l) {
            var lang = this.state[l]
            lang[t] = e.target.value
            this.setState({[l] : lang}, () => { this.setData() })
        } else {
            this.setState({[t]:e.target.value}, () => { this.setData() })
        }
    }
```

And the implementation:

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'eng')}
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'span')}
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'type')}
```

Those occur on multiple inputs and there are a few other places, those are just 3 to give example.

I'd guess the best way to handle this is to use a switch, and each case is setEng, setSpan, setType, but I wanted to see if there were any other ways to replicate this that people know of? This seems like a bit of a shortcoming of useState that setState handled really nicely.

Edit:

As requested, state as it was in class component:

```
        this.state = {
            id: this.props.count,
            collapsed: false,
            type: '',
            answer: null,
            english: {
                title: '',
                options: [],
            },
            spanish: {
                title: '',
                options: [],
            }
        }
```

And in functional component:

```
    const [id, setId] = useState(props.count)
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false)
    const [type, setType] = useState('')
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(null)
    const [english, setEnglish] = useState({ title: '', options: [] })
    const [spanish, setSpanish] = useState({ title: '', options: [] })
```

Comment: can you show how you state looks like in class compnent?

Comment: @NullPointerException updated the original question with an edit

Comment: @Alex you have to store all data in single  state, i.e ```const [state, setState] = useState({ id, answer, english, spanish })``` to get that old style working..

Comment: @bogdanoff Is that acceptable use? For some reason, I had thought that was anti-pattern... but it does make sense as a usable option.

Comment: @Alex not anipattern, just preference. Both have equal amount of pros/cons, so use depending on what you are doing.if you have more data/states, then storing in a single object makes sense. You can use individual states, but managing sometimes can be problematic.

Comment: @bogdanoff This really changes the way I am able to see FCs (in a much more positive light). Thanks for explaining/clarifying that for me!